# Custom variables in project.json

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a syntax for declaring custom variables and having them expanded in `project.json`?

```
{
  "AspNetversion": "1.0.0-beta4", // custom variable

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost": "$(AspNetversion)", // expansion
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

Comment: The following post may be helpful: http://forums.asp.net/t/2048539.aspx?How+to+read+AppSettings+in+the+controller+ASP+NET+MVC+6+

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add custom data in `project.json` but you can use the configuration system to add application settings https://github.com/aspnet/configuration